# Is there a way to get the maximum possible size of a gzip/brotli encoded string?

Tags: compression, gzip, brotli

I need to send a string of comma delimited numbers through to an API. The numbers are in the range 0-99, they are sorted in ascending order (but this can be done on our end either when creating the string, or when we lookup the string later), each number is either present or omitted (no duplicates), and the string has to contain **at least one number** (up to all 100 within the range). To my knowledge, this is a [combination without repetition](https://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/combinations-and-permutations?n=100&k=11&order=0&repeat=0), and because the string can contain a single number up to all 100, [we do a summation where the number of selected elements is 1-100](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B100%21%2Ck%21%5C%2840%29100-k%5C%2841%29%21%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C100%7D%5D).
The math behind the number of possible combinations (that makes up the string) doesn't really matter, but there is a significant number of possible combinations.

If I create a string of all 100 numbers in the range of 0-99 like so:

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99

The resultant string has a length of `289` characters - this is the maximum length of the string (in plaintext). This is a problem because the API only supports a **maximum** size of `255` characters for this field. I can compress of the string to shorten it (the format that we send to the API doesn't really matter as long as we can recover the plaintext later), but **it has to be present**.

If I gzip the aforementioned string, I get:

> H4sIAAAAAAAACg2QSQEAMAzCDOVRete/sU0AkGAIJ0iKZlgOGRJyFChRoUaDFh1u+M84HnjihTc++OJHGCHiVwaRRBFNDLHEkUaKdPIvJllkk0MueZRRopwK6gMV1dRQSx1ttGing0768zY99NLHGCPGmWCSKebrDLPMscaKdTbYZItt9tsue5xx4pwLLrnimhvun3EPU7LMNyEBAAA=

The gzip-compressed string is `212` characters - which fits within the `255` character limit.

If I switch from gzip compression to Brotli, I get:

> GyAB6I2ULmco0rFhLAZ3gWApSZCLltuPx6fnl9c3b989fACEYATFYHH8BEnRDMvh8vQFUZIVVaPV+RumZTuux+vLD8IoTtJMNtdflFXdtJ1ub/5gOBpPpjOzc/sXy9V6s93Z3bt/OJ7Ol+vNuQM=

The Brotli-compressed string is `148` characters long - which is a significant saving compared to both plaintext and gzip.

I know that lossless compression algorithms (like gzip and Brotli) work based on their ability to remove redundant data. My concern is that since the plaintext string is a combination of the numbers 0-99, and there are a lot of possible combinations, that there could be combinations (with little redundancy) that compress to more than `255` characters. I'm also not sure whether there are any cases where the compressed string would exceed the length of the the two samples above (where the maximum length plaintext is reduced to `212` chars with gzip/`148` chars with Brotli).

Does anyone know if there is a way for me to find the upper bound for the compressed string length given all of the possible permutations?

Comment: for such range I'd use single 100 bit mask (sent as 16 bytes)

Comment: Thanks to my tunnelvision, I didn't even think of doing this. Excellent suggestion!

I'm unable to mark your comment as an answer, but I will switch to your idea.